# Nested createEffect doesn't refire

Tags: javascript, typescript, solid-js

I am not sure, if I have correctly reproduced my problem but here it is:

On render signal, I have some sort of object creation that leads to more create effects that depend on update signal. But somehow the scope gets disposed and it only fires once at creation time. Even though I have references to these objects, how can I make sure nested createEffect keeps firing?

```
import { render } from 'solid-js/web';
import { on, createSignal, createEffect } from 'solid-js'

function HelloWorld() {

  let [render, setRender] = createSignal(undefined, { equals: false })

  let [update, setUpdate] = createSignal(undefined, { equals: false })
let i = 0

  createEffect(on(render, () => {
    if (i++ === 1) {
      createEffect(on(update, () => {
        console.log('inside')
      }))
    }
  }))

  createEffect(on(update, () => {
    console.log('regular', i)
  }))

 setInterval(() => {
   setUpdate();
    setRender();
  })
  return <div>Hello World!</div>;
}

render(() => <HelloWorld />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

I want `regular` and `inside` logs on every interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `createRoot` to overwrite the root of the nested `createEffect`. Otherwise it will be disposed on each rerun of the "parent" effect.

```
createEffect(() => {
   createRoot(dispose => {
      // effect will be disposed only when
      // the dispose() fn get's called
      createEffect(() => {...})
   })
})
```

https://playground.solidjs.com/?hash=-999371052&version=1.3.13

Comment: how would I have known or debug this issue, and what are the implications of this solution. Why is solid-js a mess of complication spagetthi code. Btw, I rewrote solid-js for a 2d webgl rendering library I am using, so I have some familiarity with internals.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer how this works, and what controls disposing of scopes. For example why the components not get disposed or what is the default root of the createEffect, why does it only effect nested stuff.

Comment: As far as I know only two things can dispose computations: roots and other computations. With roots you have an explicit control over that, with computations that happens before the rerun. I believe the owner of the top-level effect in your example is the render function, that is executed once and never disposes. So your top-lever effect follows the same rules as the nested one, it's just that the owner to which it belongs never needs to be disposed. For the nested one it happens whenever the signal changes. It may sound complicated, but everything is following these rules consistently.